# How to ignore errors in pyzipcode

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, zipcode

When trying to convert zip codes to state in a dataframe
Code :

```
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase

zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()


df4[‘state’] = df4[‘postal_code’].map(lambda x: zcdb[x].state)
```

Throws an error

```
“Couldnt find zipcode : ‘39826’”
```

Need to ignore this error and move on to the next row

Comment: try/except. Make a [mcve] and post the exact error message if you want specifics.

Comment: `map(lambda x: z.state if (z := zcdb.get(x)) else '')`.

Comment: You have not shown the full exact error, so we cannot tell you how to avoid it...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways. The older pattern is [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```py
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase

ZCDB = ZipCodeDatabase()

def get_state(postal_code: int) -> str | None:
    try:
        return ZCDB[x].state
    except KeyError:
        return None

df4[‘state’] = df4[‘postal_code’].map(get_state)
```

The more modern pattern is to use [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress)

```py
import contextlib

from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase

ZCDB = ZipCodeDatabase()

def get_state(postal_code: int) -> str | None:
    with contextlib.suppress(KeyError):
        return ZCDB[x].state
    return None


df4[‘state’] = df4[‘postal_code’].map(get_state)
```

There's also a slightly hacky way, looking the [`pyzipcode` source](https://github.com/vangheem/pyzipcode/blob/master/pyzipcode/__init__.py#L168):

```py
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase

ZCDB = ZipCodeDatabase()

class FakeZip:
    state = None

default = FakeZip()

df4[‘state’] = df4[‘postal_code’].map(lambda x: ZCDB.get(x, default).state)
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for: "ignore this error ***and move on to the next row***". Your code examples will fail early instead of skipping over missing values.

Comment: Ah, right, it's using map, I missed that. Let me make an edit.

Comment: Using any kind of exception-handling in this scenarion is unnecessary. The [zip db provides a get method](https://github.com/vangheem/pyzipcode/blob/master/pyzipcode/__init__.py#L168), so as I suggested earlier, a simple one-liner will do: `lambda x: z.state if (z := zcdb.get(x)) else ''`.

Comment: This is true, but the other patterns are illustrative for more complex scenarios, so I've left them.

Comment: Your `lambda` version would be more efficient if you used a global instance of `FakeZip` instead of creating a new one for every call.

Comment: Having said that, if you're averse to the walrus operator, get rid of the hacky redundant class, and just define a function instead: `def get_zip(code): z = zcbd.get(code) if z is not None: return z.state`.

Comment: Not necessarily averse. But I think the answer has already skinned this cat enough ways :p